# Analytical formula for $\int_{r_{\text{min}}}^{r_{\text{max}}} r^2dr j_{l}(kr)j_{l'}(k'r)$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

I am trying to find an analytical formula for the following integral of spherical bessel functions.
$$
R_{l,l'}(k,k')\equiv\int_{r_{\text{min}}}^{r_{\text{max}}} dr\ r^2  j_{l}(kr)j_{l'}(k'r)
$$
The case $l=l'$ is doable using the differential equation which defines
the spherical Bessel functions, which gives the identity
$$\big[k'^2 - k^2\big]\int_{r_\min}^{r_\max}dr\,r^2
\,j_\ell(kr)\,j_{\ell}(k'r)= \bigg[kr^2j'_\ell(kr)j_\ell(k'r)
-k'r^2j'_\ell(k'r)j_\ell(kr)\bigg] \bigg|_{r_\min}^{r_\max}$$
however the case $l \neq l'$ is stumping me. Any ideas?